# angularjs restrict directive scope

Tags: angularjs

I have three controllers, one parent and two nested controllers that are siblings in the DOM. All contain a property called "customisation". The two nested controllers use a directive that creates/binds a DOM element to the "customisation" property. My issue, is that a change to the value of the bound DOM property in one nested controller is changing the value in it's sibling nested controller.

I'm assuming it is something to do with the scope of the directive. I wish to restrict the scope of the directive to the individual controller so as not to affect the parent controller or any siblings.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the controller in you directive.

```
app.directive( 'directive', function () {
  return {
    controller: 'CtrlName'
  };
});
```

Or you can create your own scope for the directive.

```
app.directive('directive', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.customisation = ...
    }]
  };
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. What if I am using the same directive twice? Once inside the scope of each nested controller. Is it possible?